# Why char array is not printing value?

Tags: c++, c++11

I need to read back 'id' and 'port' from char array. But cout does not print anything. What is the correct way to do it?

Thank you for your help.

```cpp
int main() {
    char addr[6];
    int id = 2;
    short port = 1;
    memcpy(&addr[0], &id, sizeof(int));
    memcpy(&addr[4], &port, sizeof(short));

    cout << "addres:" << addr << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `addr` contains no printable characters. Fortunately it is filled properly and does contain terminating null so there is no UB here.

Comment: What output do you expect?

Answer (score 3):

Because, assuming int is 32 bit on your target platform, you are copying 4 bytes (`0, 0, 0, 2` or `2, 0, 0, 0`, depending on endianness) into the address pointed to by `addr`, and assuming short is 16 bit, you are copying 2 bytes (`0, 1` or `1, 0`, depending on endianness) at the address pointed to by `addr+4`, causing `addr` to contain the bytes `0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1` or `2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0`.

C-style strings in C++ are 0-terminated, so if the first char is 0, `addr` is interpreted as an empty string.

If the first char is 2, you still won't see anything, because that's not a printable character. (It's the control character STX (Start of Text).)

Answer (score 0):

You can print the integral values of the contents of `addr` to understand what's there.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i )
{
    std::cout << "element " << i << " : " << static_cast<int>(addr[i]) << std::endl;
}
```

You will most likely get:

```
element 0 : 2
element 1 : 0
element 2 : 0
element 3 : 0
element 4 : 1
element 5 : 0
```

That assumes that:

1. `sizeof(int)` is 4 on your platform.
2. `sizeof(short)` is 2 on your platform.
3. Your platform uses little endian system for numbers.

When you use

```
    cout << "addres:" << addr << endl;
```

You are printing a string that has an unprintable character in the first element and a null character at the second element, i.e. you are printing a null terminated string that contains only a non-printable character.